# cannot do composer update

Tags: php, laravel

I try to do composer update but keep getting this error. i try to change the requirement but still not solving the issue.

I try to do composer update but keep getting this error. i try to change the requirement but still not solving the issue.Btw this is someone project that i download to make as reference.

This is my composer.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GaWe.png)

This is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frKes.png)

Comment: Paste your composer.json here and also the error here for us to help you.

Comment: you have to decrease your php version in order to run that command for xampp you can visit this link https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-downgrade-php-from-8-0-0-to-7-1-32-in-xampp-8-0-0/ and for wampp http://blog.astemplates.com/change-php-version-wamp/

Answer (score 0):

laravel/framework v5.8 (old version) is not compatible with PHP 8, you need to upgrade to a newer version of it